# Can't find SQLPATH registry entry Oracle 11.2 Express

Tags: oracle, registry, environment-variables

I'm trying to start working through Tom Kyte's book, "Expert Oracle Database Architecture" and have run into a snag. Tom recommends creating a custom login.sql script and briefly mentions setting the SQLPATH environment variable.

I've been following the instructions found here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch2.htm#i1133354

I've searched for the SQLPATH and HOME0 keys, and for the ORACLE_HOME\DBS value, but it doesn't seem to exist in the Registry. I have Oracle 11.2 Express, Windows 8, and my Oracle instance name is the default, XE. In the Registry, I  see

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    SOFTWARE
        ORACLE
            KEY_XE
                ...
                ORACLE_HOME (value: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
                ORACLE_HOME_KEY
                ORACLE_HOME_NAME
                ...
                ODE
                    ...
                OLEDB
                    ...
            ODP.NET
                2.112.2.0\
                4.112.2.0\
            OracleMTSRecoveryService
                Protid_0
                Setup
                    All Versions
                        1\
                    Current Version\
```

Is it possible that the SQLPATH variable is no longer created by default, and that I need to just create a new one? If so, exactly where should it exist? If not, then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLPATH is a Windows system-or user environment variable not found under KEY_XE.
You can set the SQLPATH like this: Right-click on "Computer" -> Properties -> Advanced Settings - Environment

```
me@XE>host set SQLPATH
SQLPATH=c:\projects\oracle\sqlplus

-- verification
me@XE>@[%SQLPATH%]
SP2-0310: unable to open files "[c:\projects\oracle\sqlplus].sql
```

Bjarte

Comment: OK, I created a new system environment variable, and it shows up in the Registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Session Manager\Environment. However, when logged in as sys@xe, running your first command, "host set SQLPATH", the response is "Environment variable SQLPATH not defined".

Comment: Your cmd.exe prosess does not pick up this change. Launch a new cmd.exe and SQLPATH will be visible.